# Image in image (badge) css woocommerce archive

Tags: css, woocommerce, product

I created a function for my wookommerce shop so that the tag `Goratex` automatically insert badges to the product in the archive.

My problem is CSC stylization, I can't insert that badge on the product image, it cropps the image of the product itself.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnfRi.png)

```
    <div class="badgeGoratex">
echo '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/goretex-logo.png" />';
    </div>
  
CSS

.badgeGoratex {
position: relative;
float: right;
margin-top: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: try using absolute position in `badgeGoratex` like this: ```.badgeGoratex {position: absolute; top:30px;right: 30px; margin: 0;}```

Comment: I've tried it before, but then the badge hides behind the product image.

https://imgur.com/CTlyoSc

Comment: Used `z-index: 1` in or more the product image in `badgeGoratex `